# WizardHandler.wizard().goTo

Tags: angularjs, wizard

Im using https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard to create an angular wizard whose steps can be called from route params:

- .../step/1
- .../step/2

etc.

So I've created this controller:

```
.controller('createOrganizer', ['$scope', 'WizardHandler' , '$routeParams',
    function($scope,WizardHandler,$routeParams)
    {
        //$scope.data = {};
        $step = $routeParams.step;
        WizardHandler.wizard().goTo($step);     
    }])
```

The proper linking and routing were created correctly on app.js and the index.html

But when I get into the urls, I get this:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'goTo' of undefined
```

Is this the way to pre-select an angular-wizard step using url parameters?

================= Update =====================

I tried with something like this:

.controller('createOrganizer', ['$scope', 'WizardHandler' , '$routeParams',
    function($scope,WizardHandler,$routeParams)
    {
        $step = $routeParams.step;

```
    $scope.$watch(WizardHandler.wizard(), function(step) {
            WizardHandler.wizard().goTo($step);
    });
}])
```

The idea is to ise watch to tell me when WizardHandler.wizard() is instantiated in order to call the .goTo method. With this controller im getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined

Not sure if i am using watch correctly. I even tested the step variable and it is ok, showing the same value as the url.

================= Solved! =====================

```
    var step = parseInt($routeParams.step); // Important, as routeParams returns an String: the wizardHandler uses either an integer number or a string name of step. So I am parsing the number to prevent confusion.
    $scope.$watch(
    function() {return WizardHandler.wizard();}, 
    function (wizard) {
    if (wizard) wizard.goTo(step);
    });
```

I added an init(step) function that handles the initial values of some values i need and also prevents error caused by urls like .../step/SOMERANDOMSTRING

Thanks to GregL for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading through the source code quickly, my first guess would be that you have used a `<wizard>` element with a `name` property specified, but you have not passed that same name to `WizardHandler.wizard()`. In the code, if you don't specify a name argument to `WizardHandler.wizard()`, it will use the default name, which is the name used by a `<wizard>` with no `name` attribute.

Since you are not getting back the wizard you are intending when you call `WizardHandler.wizard()`, it resolves to `undefined` and calling `goTo()` will fail with the error you got.

At the very least, separate the getting of the wizard and the `.goTo()` call to add a check in to make sure you got a valid wizard:

```
.controller('createOrganizer', ['$scope', 'WizardHandler' , '$routeParams',
    function($scope,WizardHandler,$routeParams)
    {
        //$scope.data = {};
        $step = $routeParams.step;
        var wizard = WizardHandler.wizard();
        if (wizard)
            wizard.goTo($step);
    }]);
```

There should probably be a `var` keyword before that `$step` assignment, too, and as a convention, only Angular core things should start with a `$`, or jQuery selection variables.

**EDIT:** You could also try using a `$watch()` to get notified when the wizard is loaded, however there is no guarantee that the `$digest()` cycle will be called immediately after the wizard is loaded, so you would be relying on the assumption that the $apply/$digest cycle is run sometime after the wizard is correctly added to the `WizardHandler`'s cache.

You would do this like so:

```
.controller('createOrganizer', ['$scope', 'WizardHandler' , '$routeParams',
    function($scope,WizardHandler,$routeParams)
    {
        //$scope.data = {};
        $step = $routeParams.step;
        $scope.$watch(function() {
            return WizardHandler.wizard();
        }, function (wizard) {
            if (wizard)
                wizard.goTo($step);
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: *Disclaimer:* I have not yet used this component to verify my answer. Though it may just be the ideal component for an app I am working on at the moment, and your question alerted me to it, so thanks for asking it!

Comment: I think it is more like a race condition. The Wizard.Handler.wizard() property is not even instantiated when I ask for the goTo method.

Comment: I tried with something like this:       .controller('createOrganizer', ['$scope', 'WizardHandler' , '$routeParams',
    function($scope,WizardHandler,$routeParams)
    {
     $step = $routeParams.step;

     $scope.$watch(WizardHandler.wizard(), function(step) {
            WizardHandler.wizard().goTo($step);
     });
    }])

Comment: @kennyvivas Good idea about using `$watch()`, I updated my answer to show the correct way of doing what you tried.

Comment: Great! Actually you just nailed! but I had to make some minor amends to the code in order to make it work (stupid one actually, i had to parseInt the routeParams step variable.) Check on the update and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to access the wizard instance when it is not yet initialized. If you wrap it in a `$timeout`, it should work (and is less complicated compared to `$watch` solution above):

```
$timeout(function() {
    WizardHandler.wizard().goTo($step); 
});
```